# Como criar vários objetos a partir de uma struct tendo seus valores definidos pelo usuário ( Ponteiros e Malloc)

Tags: c, c++

Então, no exercício preciso exibir, no máximo, 10 produtos com nome, quantidade e valor inseridos pelo usuário usando o terminal e depois exibir tudo na tela.

**Mas** eu só sei criar um único "objeto" dessa classe:

```
Produto *produto1 = (Produto*)malloc(sizeof(Produto));
```

Eu precisava de algo com **produto[0]**, **produto[1]**, **produto[2]**!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    char nome;
    int quantidade;
    double preco;
} Produto;

void Inicializa (Produto *conta, char nome, int quantidade, double preco) {
    conta->nome = nome;
    conta->quantidade = quantidade;
    conta->preco = preco;
}

void Imprime (Produto *conta) {
    cout << endl << conta->nome;
    cout << endl << conta->quantidade;
    cout << endl << conta->preco << endl;
}

int main () {

    

> Produto *produto1 = (Produto*)malloc(sizeof(Produto));


    printf("\n+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");
    printf("\n|                            Pedido de Produtos                              |\n");
    printf("\n+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  - -- - - - - -+\n");
    printf("\n| Digite o nome, quantidade solicitada e preco unitario do produto desejado: |\n");
    printf("\n+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+\n");

    Inicializa(produto1, 'c', 2, 33.33);

    Imprime(produto1);

    return 0;
}
```

Mais uma duvida como pego e armazeno um string inteira, tipo: "Nome do Produto".

Agradeço a atenção.

Comment: Antes de tudo acho que devia escolher qual linguagem vai usar? C ou C++? E a partir daí começar seu programa com struct/malloc em C ou usar classe e vetores por exemplo em C++

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia usar vetor(array):

```
Produto produtos[100];
```

Assim vc acessaria por `produtos[0]`, `produtos[1]`, etc...

Ou, já que vc está usando ponteiros, você poderia criar uma [lista encadeada](https://www.ime.usp.br/%7Epf/algoritmos/aulas/lista.html):

```
struct produto {
    char nome;
    int quantidade;
    double preco;
    struct produto *prox;
};
typedef struct produto Produto;
```

E acessaria o próximo produto da lista com:

```
Produto *prox_prod = prod->prox;
```